# Lower bound on the covering radius of a code

Tags: coding-theory

Let $C$ be a $[n,k]$ linear code over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Suppose that $\rho$ is the covering radius .

I want to show that $\rho \geq \frac{n-k}{1+ \log_q{(n)}}$.

Could you give me a hint how we could show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use a sphere packing argument, only for covering. Let $V_q(\rho)$ be the volume of a Hamming ball of radius $\rho$. The Hamming balls around all codewords cover the entire space, so $V_q(\rho) q^k \geq q^n$, or $V_q(\rho) \geq q^{n-k}$. To deduce the bound, use an approximation for $V_q(\rho)$.

Comment: I'm afraid your formula is incorrect. For example, $V_q(1) = 1 + n(q-1)$. The value depends on $n$.

Comment: You'll have to work that out. There are many approximations out there, then you can find in any textbook, or online. You can also work back and see what approximation gives the required bound, and then try to prove it or to look it up. Good luck!

Comment: You tell me. Good luck!

Comment: There are standard bounds, and one of them probably works. You can look at the list as well as I can.

Comment: The same book where this exercise is taken from.

Comment: Whatever source you found it in assumed that you are aware of the bound that you need to use.

Comment: Then you should ask whoever gave you the exercise.

Comment: You can find some approximation here: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~venkatg/teaching/codingtheory/notes/notes2.pdf. It was the first hit for `volume of hamming ball` on google.